# Fonts to match TeX Gyre Pagella

Tags: fonts

I want to use the `TeX Gyre Pagella` font for the main text. I have the problem to find match math and sans serif fonts to it.

- I would like to use the `TeX Gyre Pagella Math`, but for this I have to use `unicode-math` because this font is only in `otf` format.
- But then I can not use 'Bera Sans' because is only in adobe format.

Has any one some suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried `mathastext`?

Comment: @Seamus: I did not look to that. I would prefer to use proper fonts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you insist on Type 1 fonts (cf. [Wikipedia: PostScript fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_fonts)), you could use the package `mathpazo`. Load this before loading of TeX Gyre Pagella, because `mathpazo` itself redefines also `\rmdefault` to a Palatino variant.

If you want to use OTF/TTF fonts – what usually means you must use Lua(La)TeX or Xe(La)TeX –, you could use “DejaVu Sans” as replacement for “Bera Sans” – the whole [DejaVu fonts](http://dejavu-fonts.org/) project is derived from the Vera fonts, from whome the Bera fonts themselves are derived (and BTW also the Arev fonts). For loading you do not need directly the `fontspec` call, but can write `\usepackage{DejaVuSans}`.

Comment: I like the option of DejaVuSans. It aslo can be used with lualatex via `fontspec`

Comment: tex-gyre math covers pagella, too.  only available in otf, though.

Answer (score 2):

Try [pxfonts](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pxfonts) with `\usepackage{tgpagella,qpxmath}`.